# How to clear/remove all rows for ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I am trying to clear all current rows from my ag-grid. I tried to do this:

```
aggridOptions.api.setRowData([]);
```

but this adds me "No rows to show" dialog, then when I am updating the grid with new data the dialog is still appears.

Is there correct way to clear the grid from data rows?

Comment: have you tried setDatasource()?

Comment: This only sets new datasource. As I am using angular way and loading the data from server side by using aggridOptions.api.addItems(data) I am not using the datasource feature.

Comment: " then when I am updating the grid with new data" How are you updating the data?

Comment: Are you talking about this [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/index.php)? because I am not seeing any addItems function

Comment: you can see it here : https://ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-insert-remove/index.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've taken a look and this is bug - we'll issue a fix for it in the next release. We'll be issuing a new release on Friday, which will include the fix for this - the next version will be ag-grid 6.3.0.

In the meantime, you can add the following line after `addItems` which should remove the overlay:

```
gridOptions.api.hideOverlay()
```

As I say though, from Friday this line won't be necessary

Comment: so from friday doing this : aggridOptions.api.setRowData([]); is the correct way to clear the grid (without doing gridOptions.api.hideOverlay())?

Comment: thats correct - its not actually the setRowData that is the problem, it is that the addItems isnt clearing the overlay